# Generating SSH id_dsa.pub, but then I cannot find in SSH directory

Tags: macos, ssh, github

I am trying to connnect to github, but am getting a Permission denied (publickey) error. I generated new id_rsa.pub and put them in my account at github, but this didn't help. I then tried to create new id_dsa.pub and id_dsa keys, `ssh-keygen -t dsa`. However, when I go to try to copy the id_dsa.pub key I am told the directory does not exist.

Note I am using Mac OSX

```
skline-mac:first_app skline$ sudo ssh-keygen -t dsaPassword:
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/root/.ssh/id_dsa): 
/var/root/.ssh/id_dsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa.
Your public key has been saved in /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
ba:26:95:3e:11:bb:b7:32:01:ae:14:fe:d9:2a:03:0e root@skline-mac.local
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ DSA 1024]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|  . . .          |
| . o . +S        |
|E o . *.         |
|oo o =.+         |
| .+ + O..        |
|   o.+.=..       |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact commands you used and the output into your question?  Please indent each line by 4 spaces so that it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Why are you generating keys as root? Why can't you just generate keys as your own user, where it will just make the file at /home/username/.ssh/?

Comment: Good call; I had just assumed he was generating the key for root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that the directory isn't traversable for anybody but root (execute bit isn't set on the directory).

Try first getting a root shell, with `sudo -s` then copying the file (and you may also want to change owners after you do.

So:

```
$ sudo -s
# cp /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub DESTINATION
# chown USER:USER DESTINATION
# exit
$ cat DESTINATION
```